# Characterization of edge posets

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, posets

Given an acyclic directed graph  $G$, the set $E(G)$ of edges of $G$ equipped with the reachable order $\to$ is called the **edge poset** of $G$, where for two edges $e_1\to e_2$ means that there is a directed path starting from $e_1$ ending with $e_2$.

My question is that how can we characterize those edge posets of acyclic directed graphs, or under exactly what conditions a poset can be represented as the edge poset of an acyclic directed graph?

A closely related result is stated in the paper "Planarity and Edge Poset Dimension", at page 733, where the authors said that:

*Posets which are edge partial orders of graphs have been fully characterized (see , for
example , [13]) . They are called N-free partial orders as they do not contain any
N-shaped configuration . They are also characterized by the property that any maximal
chain intersects any maximal antichain . We have the following property :

**PROPERTY 3** . Each N - free partial order is the edge - partial order of an unique
e - bipolarly oriented graph.*

This result means that the edge poset of an
e-bipolarly oriented graph (or equivalently, an st-graph
/PERT-graph) can be characterized by the property of N-freeness.

But I do not agree with the statement that posets which are edge partial orders of graphs have been fully characterized, which is what my question concerns.

Comment: Isn't this the transitive closure of the DAG? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy No. The elements of the "edge poset" are the edges, not the vertices. For instance, the $4$-element poset whose Hasse diagram looks like the letter N can not be represented as an edge poset.

Comment: @Matthieu Latapy
Yes, the reachable order of vertices is exactly the transitive closure of the adjacency relation of a DGA. But my question is about the reachable order of edges, not of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The result that each N - free partial order is the edge - partial order of an unique e - bipolarly oriented graph, implies that  a poset is an edge poset if and only if it is N-free.

**Proof**:$(\Rightarrow)$ We prove that edge posets are N-free by contradiction. Suppose $P$ is the edge-poset of acyclic directed graph $G$ and is not N-free, then it contains a **covering-subposet** $N$ with four elements $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $a$ covers $b$, $c$ covers $b$, $c$ covers $d$, $a||c$, $a||d$ and $b||d$. Evidently, the edges conrresponding to $a,b,c,d$ and their incident vertices form a sub acyclic directed graph of $G$ (an edge-induced subgraph), whose edge-poset is $N$. This contradicts with  the fact that $N$ can not be an edge-poset.

$(\Leftarrow)$ This direction is a direct consequence of the fact that any N-free poset is the edge poset of an unique PERT-graph.

The conrrespondence between N-free posets and acyclic directed graphs are one-to-many. In fact, we can freely combine and split the sources and sinks of an acyclic directed graph, respectively, without changing its edge-poset. It is natural to introduce the following notion.

Two acyclic directed graphs are **EP-equivalent** if they have the same edge-poset.